# ansible error when use unarchive module on local system

Tags: ansible

Pls. Help
I`m have this playbook:

```
---
- name: Install service
  hosts: some_host
  vars:
    app: "{{ app_name }}-{{ tag }}.war"
    app_folder: "{{ client_dir }}/{{ app_name }}"

  tasks:
   - name: Unpack archive Java
     unarchive:
      src={{ java_distrib }}
      dest={{ app_folder }}
      creates="{{ app_folder }}/{{ java_home }}"
      mode=0555
```

all work fine when i install on remote host.
But when hosts is same machine from i run ansible-playbook i got this error:

```
        TASK [Unpack archive Java] *********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.2.9.6]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 10.2.9.6 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/stend/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1586175452.58-42679814338845/AnsiballZ_unarchive.py\", line 114, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/home/stend/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1586175452.58-42679814338845/AnsiballZ_unarchive.py\", line 106, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/home/stend/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1586175452.58-42679814338845/AnsiballZ_unarchive.py\", line 49, in invoke_module\r\n    imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_unarchive_payload_f_poEj/__main__.py\", line 157, in <module>\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_unarchive_payload_f_poEj/ansible_unarchive_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/urls.py\", line 402, in <module>\r\nAttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HTTPSConnection'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

and i`m not understand whats going on. Why connection closed? i`m try unarchive to local machine. Where i`m wrong? Pls help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, i`m re install python and library libssl1.1